# Access implemented class method

Tags: c#, oop

I want to ask one question about inherit. 
I have two class which implemented from AbsDoc

```
public class A:AbsDoc
{
     public void SomeMethodA()
     {}
}


public class B:AbsDoc
{
     public void SomeMethod()
     {}
}

and one class to implement 

public class AbsDoc
{
     public void Doit(){};
     public void DoDiff(){};
}
```

When i need to access class A or B methods like this i am getting error how can i access

```
AbsDoc temp=null; 

if(param=="A)
{
  temp=new A();
}
else 
{
  temp=new B();
}

temp.SomeMethodA();//it gets error when i try to access
```

Comment: That gives a compile time error, because SomeMethodA() exists ONLY on A. AbsDoc has no knowledge of SomeMethod or SomeMethodA. So, either you need to cast it to the right type or define the method in your base class and create the implementation in your derived classes.

Comment: have you read up on how to Instantiate new Objects in C#

Comment: i have read  how to Instantiate new Objects in C# please you read my comment below and answer it if you know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`temp` as you've defined it is an `AbsDoc`. It doesn't have a `SomeMethodA` so you'll get a compiler error. That's expected. For example, look at your code again:

```
AbsDoc temp=null; 

if(param=="A")
{
  temp=new A();
}
else 
{
  temp=new B();
}

temp.SomeMethodA();//it gets error when i try to access
```

What's supposed to happen if `param != "A"`? Your `temp` will be a `B` instead of an `A` and so you can't call `SomeMethodA`. If you want to call `SomeMethodA`, you'll need to cast `temp`:

```
AbsDoc temp=null; 

if(param=="A")
{
  temp=new A();
  ((A)temp).SomeMethodA();
}
else 
{
  temp=new B();
  ((B)temp).SomeMethod();
}
```

From your comment, it looks like what you want to do is something like this:

```
AbsDoc temp=null; 

if(param=="A")
{
  var a =new A();
  a.SomeMethodA();
  temp = a;
}
else 
{
  var b =new B();
  v.SomeMethod();
  temp = b;
}

temp.DoIt();
```

That way you don't need to do all the base class stuff twice.

Comment: I have wanted to do every job with one variable(temp).Is it a good way to above code ?

Comment: You haven't given enough context to answer that question. You can't call methods or access properties that are specific to `A` or `B` from a variable typed as `AbsDoc` unless you cast it.

Comment: I understand I don't access properties or method to cast A or B but if a create A tempA = new A() tempa.absdocmethod(); and B tempB=new B() tempB.absdocmethod() i will have write two times absdoctmethod(). I want to write one time your answer is enough for me but which is the best way for you ?